# What's the purpose of function aligning?

Tags: c++, c, function, alignment, memory-alignment

I'm trying to understand why to align functions. For example there's `-falign-functions` option in gcc, which aligns functions to n-byte boundaries, but what's the purpose?

Comment: presumably as an optimization on some platforms. oh, would you look at that. it's listed under "Options That Control Optimization".

Comment: Depends on the processor.  For Intel's, this is covered by chapter 3.4.1.5 of the optimization manual, recommending alignment of branch targets to 16 bytes.  Nice for the instruction prefetcher.